# NSubstitute analyzer giving a warning incorrectly?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, nsubstitute

While using the NuGet NSubstitute 4.3.0 and NSubstitute.Analyzers.CSharp, I am trying to intercept a call as follows.

```
_someMock = Substitute.For<IInterface>();
_someMock.ReceivedWithAnyArgs().ExtensionMethod(default);
```

Here actual names are changed for illustration. `ExtensionMethod` is an extension method defined on `IInterface`. Apparently Nsubstitute.Analyzers.CSharp is generating the following warning.

> NS1001: Member ExtensionMethod can not be intercepted. Only interface
> members and virtual, overriding, and abstract members can be
> intercepted.

This is understandable as `ExtensionMethod` actually is an extension method (and not of one of the permitted types).

However, surprisingly, the desired call gets intercepted exactly as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally answering my own question; the code presented above indeed compiles and executes, but after all, it does *not* intercept the call to the extension method as it appeared. In total, the warning given by NSubstitute.Analyzers.CSharp is correct. Interception of calls to extension methods is not possible.